# Broadcast receiver calling itself more than 1 time

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have my broadcast receiver inside the foreground service.
I'm detecting the incoming call and executing some method whenever the call cuts but the problem is the method is calling itself more than once and causing duplicate data.

I want to know why my broadcast receiver is calling itself more than 1 time when it is supposed to be called only once.

I have inserted log statement just to trace the Broadcast receiver and I'll share the result.

Broadcast Receiver-

```
   BroadcastReceiver b = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            k=k+1;
            Log.d("whats", "onreceive: "+k);
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Call has ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("whats", "after end: " + k);
            }
        }

    };

    IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter();
    f.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
    getBaseContext().registerReceiver(b, f);
```

Here id the result in logcat-

> ```
>     whats: onreceive: 1     
>     whats: onreceive: 2       
>     whats: onreceive: 3       
>     whats: after end: 3      
>     whats: onreceive: 4     
>     whats: after end: 4
> ```

This is the result of only one time incoming call and that call ends. 
Let me know what is wrong with this code and please provide the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously its being called with states other than STATE_IDLE the first two times, then called with STATE_IDLE twice.  I'd also be curious if you somehow registered two receivers instead of one- I'd have it print the value of this and the value of intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE) to check and see what those values are.  I would expect to see RINGING then IDLE for the call ringing then ending.  If you had 2 registered somehow that would line up perfectly.

Comment: @GabeSechan I've only one broadcast receiver.  Can you please explain again what you want to say. Not able to understand.

Comment: Depending on your full code, you may have accidentally instantiated 2 of them.  A common way of seing this is if you don't properly unregister versions when your service is destroyed, or if you instantiate them in the wrong lifecycle event.  You need to check that you aren't seeing events sent to multiple instances by printing the instance being called inside your method.  If they're all from the same reference, you're good on that.  If not, that's your problem. The other half of your problem is from being called in STATE_RINGING as well as STATE_IDLE, which is expected.